# GTK and PYGTK difference

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk2

many programmers import both gtk and pygtk in this way:

```
import gtk
import pygtk
```

I have created a simple program using only gtk and it works:

```
import gtk

window = gtk.Window()
window.set_size_request(800, 700)
window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

button = gtk.Button("Vai")
button.set_size_request(30, 35)
button.connect("clicked", naviga)
testo = gtk.Entry()

h = gtk.HBox()
h.pack_start(testo)
h.pack_start(button)

window.add(h)
window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

So... the question is: what is the difference from GTK and PYGTK ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`pygtk` is provided by `python-gobject`.
`gtk` is provided by `python-gtk2`.

`pygtk` provides the `pygtk.require` function which allows you to require that a certain version of gtk (or better) is installed. For example

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
```

importing `gtk` only is possible, but your program may not work as expected on someone else's machine if their version of gtk is older.

Comment: So pygtk is used only to require that a certain version of gtk is installed ?

Comment: @xRobot: Yes. If you open a Python REPL, and type `import pygtk; pygtk.__file__` you'll find the path to the package. It might be something like `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/pygtk.pyc`. If you take the `c` off the end of the path, and look inside the file `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/pygtk.py` you'll find it defines just three functions, and they all have to do with determining and requiring versions. It is merely by looking at this file that I am surmising/concluding what `pygtk` is for.

Answer (score 5):

I was confused by `pygtk` vs `gtk` because my test app worked fine with `gtk`.

I now realise that `gtk` means [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/index.html), the Python module that contains bindings to the [Gtk+](https://www.gtk.org) 2.x library. `pygtk` is another module, also part of [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/index.html), that can (but doesn't need to) be used to ensure a certain version of the [Gtk+](https://www.gtk.org) library.

**The `gtk` and `pytk` modules apply to Python 2 only. For Python 3 you need to use [Gtk+](https://www.gtk.org) through the `gi` [GObject Introspection](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GObjectIntrospection) module.**

The Python [GObject Introspection](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GObjectIntrospection) module (aka `gi` or `gi.repository`) is a middleware layer between C libraries (using [GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/)) and language bindings. Essentially it autogenerates Python bindings from the underlying C source code. [GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/) is the *[GLib](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GLib) Object system*, where [GLib](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GLib) provides the core application building blocks for libraries and applications written in C. [GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/) provides [GTK+](https://www.gtk.org) with object-oriented C-based APIs and automatic transparent API bindings to other compiled or interpreted languages (such as Python).

The GTK3+ library uses [Gobject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/) but the GTK2+ library does not. This means that you can not use Gtk2+ with Python version 3.

For Python 2 you'd use

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
```

or just

```
import gtk
```

For Python 3 you need

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk','3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

You can verify versions with:

For Gtk+ 2 (Python 2 or 3)

```
print("PyGTK %d.%d.%d Gtk+ %d.%d.%d" % (gtk.pygtk_version + gtk.gtk_version))
```

For Gtk+ 3 (Python 3 only)

```
print("Gtk %d.%d.%d" % (Gtk.get_major_version(),
                                         Gtk.get_minor_version(),
                                         Gtk.get_micro_version()))
```